# Programmatically move mail from Other to Focused inbox

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to move mail from Other to Focused Inbox programmatically or make whatever changes necessary in my new mail event handler so that the mail shows up in one on the other.

The reason I want to do this is because I want most of notification mails from a forum to be in the other inbox; except that when the Subject contains a certain string I want it to show up in the Focused Inbox.

The [Manage Focused Inbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/manage-focused-inbox?view=graph-rest-1.0) help page mentions `Focused Inbox REST API` and `inferenceClassification` property that controls but I do not know how to use that.

Is it possible to modify this property in VBA, or any way to move mails between the two inboxes programmatically?

I manually compared all items in `MailItem.ItemProperties` of a mail message when in Focused and Other Inbox. `inferenceClassification` is not one of the properties. The only properties with different values are `LastModificationTime` and strangely `OutlookVersion`, `OutlookInternalVersion`, and `Size`!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77573242/332059

Answer (score 1):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property or method for including/excluding items from the focused inbox list. But I think it may act like a search folder in Outlook. You just need to find out what is causing emails to appear on the list.

You can use [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi) (open-source) or `OutlookSpy` (shareware) utilities for exploring hidden properties in Outlook to find out what properties could cause an email to appear in the focused inbox.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. I did not find any interesting differences in `MailItem.ItemProperties` when a mail is in Focused versus when it is in Other Inbox, I will check hidden properties.

Comment: @MiserableVariable did you ever find the right property for this?