# Access Focused vs Other folder rules programmatically

Tags: vba, outlook, inbox

I am trying to use VBA to access the rules that build the "Inbox" views when the Focused Inbox option is turned on. When you right click on an email and ask Outlook to move all future emails to the "Other" view or back to the "Focused" view (as below), Outlook must create some sort of rule to make sure these emails are always showing up in the right place; except it doesn't give you any option to make changes or to see them (e.g. I want not only emails from jdoe@contoso.com to go to Other folder, but all *@contoso.com)

[image: Move to Other View]

[image: Screenshot Focused View]

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

I have been searching high-and-low and can't seem to find any documentation from Microsoft or anyone on where these rules are stored, how to access them, or even how to differentiate programmatically where the message sits (as both say they are in the "inbox")

The only [relevant topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71834310/programmatically-move-mail-from-other-to-focused-inbox) around this points to GrahAPI for this feature; but again, not much in the way of where the rules set, and what would it take to change those rules.

Answer (score 1):

Messages in the "Other" view have (`0x1213, PT_LONG`) MAPI property (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x12130003"`) set to 1 - you can see and edit that property in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author). Deleting the property or setting (use `MailItem.PropertyAccessor`) its value to anything but 1 will show the message in the "Focused" view.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, that is nice to know; but where are the rules that set that property ? i.e. if I want to edit that rule (as in my original question); is there anywhere in the MAPI schema that this is stored?

Comment: The condition itself is not exposed - it is hardcoded by Outlook. You cannot modify it. What you need to do is to set the property appropriately depending on whether you want a message to be shown in Focused or in Other.

Comment: Thanks for replying back, and I am sure you have a lot of insight (from developing OutlookSpy) into how Outlook internally works. However, I am sure these rules must be written somewhere, otherwise, how does Outlook determine if it should flag this as Other or focused? I can write a script to set the flag manually, but I would rather edit the rule.

Comment: Yes, that rule is hardcoded in Outlook code. Unless you work for Microsoft and can modify Outlook code, setting that property is your only choice.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are missing my question. When you right click and ask Outlook to flag all future emails as "Other" or "Focused" it must remember this somewhere? Right?

Comment: @HanyE I'm looking for this same exact thing.  Did you ever find your solution?

And I agree that when you manually flag emails to move to either inbox, that has to be stored somewhere.  That can't be hardcoded into Outlook.